# The best alternative of Math.pow in J2ME

Tags: math, java-me

What is the best alternative of the Math.pow() method in J2ME as I could come to the conclusion that J2ME does not support the Math.pow() method and some other methods such as Math.exp() and alike. I'm asking this question only to find one of the best available solutions.

Comment: did you check prior question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076913/j2me-powerdouble-double-math-function-implementation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the power of a number in J2ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516103/how-to-get-the-power-of-a-number-in-j2me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
com.steema.teechart.misc.MathUtils
```

Here's the page I got this info on

http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/com/steema/teechart/misc/MathUtils.html

Looks like you'll have to go the third party route.  If you don't like them.  Google third party math libs for J2ME.

It states it's strictly for J2ME, since J2ME doesn't have the regular Math lib `java.lang.Math`

java developers are use to.